# Arranging participants in a line

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How many ways can you arrange 10 participants in a line so that two participants, Jack and Bob, aren't sitting next to each other?

I know that 10! is the no. of permutations for 10 participants, but I cannot understand how to do this with separating 2 individuals.

Comment: See also another aryamank's [PSQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2940626).

Comment: Between this and your other question, it looks like you are just posting your homework here so that we can do it for you.

Comment: As I just said in response to [another of your questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2940626/permutations-of-anagrams), when you pose a question here, it is expected that you share your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: I am genuinely stuck on this question -- just expecting feedback on how to approach this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider first the number $N$ of configurations where Jack and Bob are sitting next each other. Let's consider for instance that Jack and Bob are conjoined twins.

Then you see that it is like arranging $9$ people the way you want, so you have $9 !$ possibilities. But now, Jack and Bob can be either the first before the second, either the second before the first. So for each possibility, you have two cases resulting of the position of Jack with respect to John.

The total number of configurations is then $N = 2 \times (9!)$.

The number of configurations where Jack and Bob are not sitting near each other is then the complement of $N$ to the total number of configurations, that is 
$$10 ! - 2 \times 9! = 8 \times 9 !$$

Comment: Thank you for your response! However, I am unclear about why you subtract it from 10 factorial.

Comment: Well first I calculated the number $N$ of "bad" configurations. So to have the number of "good" ones, I have to substrac $N$ from the total number of configurations, that is $10 !$